# select columns based on first letter of columns using grep or grepl in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am attempting to use the `dplyr` package to select all columns that start with i.  I have the following code:

```
dat <- select(newdat1,starts_with("i"))
```

and the colnames for my data are:

```
> colnames(newdat)
[1] "i22" "i21" "i20" "i24"
```

It is just a coincidence in this case they all start with i, as in other cases there will be a larger variety; thus, I want to automate the process.  The issue is it appears my code using `dplyr` is correct; however, I am having issues with the package, so I was wondering if/how to accomplish the same task with grep or grepl, or anything really using the base package.  Thanks!

Comment: Or `newdat1[,substr(names(newdat1), 1, 1) == "i"]`

Comment: Btw, this is pretty much [what `strat_with` does](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-utils.R#L1-L9) actually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With base R , you can use `grep` to match column names. You can use

```
dat <- newdat1[, grep("^i", colnames(newdat1))]
```

to do a starts-with like query. You can use any regular expression you want as the pattern in `grep()`.